# C# Discord.net 1.0.2 Sending message to specific channel

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Looking at how to send messages to specific channels. After searching around it doesn't seem to be too complicated but for some reason channel in this case is returning null, and as such an object reference not set to an instance of an object error when its used. The ID should be correct so I'm not really sure whats wrong.

```
[Command("say")]
    public async Task sayAsync([Remainder] string message)
    {
        DiscordSocketClient client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        ulong channelID = 123456789123456789; //Example ID 

        var channel = client.GetChannel(channelID) as SocketTextChannel;
        await channel.SendMessageAsync(message);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post client config file?

Comment: The App.config? Or do you mean another file.

Comment: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketConfig.html

Answer (score 2):

If anyone finds this I'll put the answer I found on the discord API discord.

I made the mistake of creating a new client and trying to find the channels inside that.

```
 DiscordSocketClient client = new DiscordSocketClient();
```

I should have been using the client that was used for the connection and thus

```
var client = Context.Client;
```

Was all that was needed to fix the issue.